# Element wise average of structure fields with arrays

Tags: matlab, struct

I have a structure called "xyz" with the following contents. How can I make a new variable (a 141x136 double) having an element wise average of the fields.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow these steps:

1. Convert the struct to a cell array.
2. Generate a comma-separated list from the cell, and concatenate the cells' contents along the third dimension, producing a 3D numeric array.
3. Compute the mean along the 3rd dimension.

Example:

```
xyz.v1 = ones(5,6);
xyz.v2 = 2*ones(5,6);  % example data
c = struct2cell(xyz);  % step 1
c = cat(3, c{:});      % step 2
result = mean(c, 3);   % step 3
```

Consider if you really need a struct. Maybe you can have the 3D array instead (depending on the rest of your code). That's usually more time- and memory-efficient. The fields would correspond to the 3rd-dim slices, and you would only need step 3 above, that is, `mean(..., 3)`.