# Finding mean of a vector in a for loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, mean

How do I get the `mean` of a vector inside a `for` loop. The vector `v` depends on `k`.

```
for k = 1:n
   filename = 'file.txt';
   ...
   v = ... %the vector
   result = mean(v, 3); %mean along the 3rd dimension.; didn't work.
end
```

Comment: is your _v_ a 3D array?

Comment: No. It's 2D. But It's changing for every iteration so I thought doing an average along the 3rd dimension (layers of array) is a better way.

Comment: If your matrix is 2D, how you expect to get _mean_ in third dimension? Have you checked what _mean(v,3)_ gives when _v_ is 2D?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43939589/6245506; sth. like this maybe?

Comment: If `v` is *really* a *vector,* you only need `result = mean(v)` and if you want to store all `k` results then   `result(k) = mean(v)`

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `result` as a cell array and keep storing the *means*. The following should work:

```
result = cell(n,1);
for k = 1:n
   filename = 'file.txt';
   ...
   v = ... %the vector
   result{k} = mean(v, 3); %mean along the 3rd dimension.; didn't work.
end
```